# Activity onDestroy onCreate methods

Tags: android, android-activity

Should I release resources when onDestroy invoked ?

Let's say I have a native jni lib and I have a connections to third party services, like google billing and so on.

For example system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space, ofc I can try to release all the resources, but it's error prone approach due some JNI specific.

What I want to do - init all resources only once, do not clean up them onDestroy, if onCreate method is called second time - do nothing, since all resources are already initialized.

What do you think about it ? What if even onDestroy called, the app is still eating some space, will OS kill it ? Even so, that's completely fine for me

Comment: I guess that if you are asking this, it means that the JNI cannot be changed to make it more easily unloadable? My first attempt would be to make this JNI code more manageable...

Comment: Why should I bother ? What are the drawbacks of my approach ?

Comment: onDestroy is only called if your application is totally closed, so you will have to create all the instances again because you application will run from the very beginning, the onDestroy method normally is used to store some transaction not finished to not loose the data. I think is valid trate the resources in onStop and onStart methods, if you clean some resources you activity may not be destroyed very often.

Comment: Wrong - onDestroy may also be called when your app is on background but not completely closed

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: "what are the drawbacks": As Lucas mentionned, onDestroy gives you an opportunity to cleanly finish anything going on - saving states if needed. Now, if you have no such states to save and don't bother your process being killed at any moment (which is bound to happen), then maybe there are no drawbacks.